Simple Merge sort code behaving strangely by working 50% of the time for the same input
I wrote the following simple code for Merge sort:
It is behaving strangely because the array: {38, 27, 43, 3, 9, 82, 10}
gets sorted as:
{3 9 10 27 38 43 82 }
and sometimes as:
{-1707474943 3 9 10 27 38 43 }
I have tried to debug this but I cant make sense of this. Why would the code work correctly only 50% of the time for the SAME input.
I can easily copy paste merge sort code but I want to understand why the code is behaving like this.
void merge(int arr[], int st, int mid, int end)
{
    mid = (st + end) / 2;     
    int len1 = mid - st + 1;
    int len2 = end - mid;

    int *first = new int[len1];
    int *second = new int[len2];

    int ind = st;
    for (int i = 0; i < len1; i++)
    {
        first[i] = arr[ind++];
    }

    ind = mid + 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < len2; j++)
    {
        second[j] = arr[ind++];
    }

    int i = 0, j = 0, k = st;
    while (i < len1 && j < len2)
    {
        if (first[i] < second[j])
        {
            arr[k++] = first[i++]; 
        }
        else if (first[i] > second[j])
        {
            arr[k++] = second[j++];
        }
        else
        {
            arr[k++] = first[i++];
            arr[k++] = second[j++];
        }
    }

    while (i < len1)
    {
        arr[k++] = first[i++];
    }

    while (j < len2)
    {
        arr[k++] = second[j++];
    }

    delete[] first;
    delete[] second;
    display(arr, st, end);
}

void mergeSort(int arr[], int st, int end)
{
    if (st >= end)
    {
        return;
    }
    int mid = (st + end) / 2;
    // cout << mid << " " << (st + end) / 2 << endl;
    mergeSort(arr, st, mid);
    mergeSort(arr, mid + 1, end); 
    merge(arr, st, mid, end);
}

void merge(int arr[], int st, int mid, int end)
{
    mid = (st + end) / 2;     
    int len1 = mid - st + 1;
    int len2 = end - mid;

    int *first = new int[len1];
    int *second = new int[len2];

    int ind = st;
    for (int i = 0; i < len1; i++)
    {
        first[i] = arr[ind++];
    }

    ind = mid + 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < len2; j++)
    {
        second[j] = arr[ind++];
    }

    int i = 0, j = 0, k = st;
    while (i < len1 && j < len2)
    {
        if (first[i] < second[j])
        {
            arr[k++] = first[i++]; 
        }
        else if (first[i] > second[j])
        {
            arr[k++] = second[j++];
        }
        else
        {
            arr[k++] = first[i++];
            arr[k++] = second[j++];
        }
    }

    while (i < len1)
    {
        arr[k++] = first[i++];
    }

    while (j < len2)
    {
        arr[k++] = second[j++];
    }

    delete[] first;
    delete[] second;
}

void mergeSort(int arr[], int st, int end)
{
    if (st >= end)
    {
        return;
    }
    int mid = (st + end) / 2;
    mergeSort(arr, st, mid);
    mergeSort(arr, mid + 1, end); 
    merge(arr, st, mid, end);
}

Ran the code for the same input (same array) 10 times and got correct answer 5 times and wrong answer 5 times.
How is this happening?

I was passing the array size size as '7' instead of '6' (0-indexed) and this was leading to the error. But why was it working 50% of the time?

When using 7 instead of 6, your also sorting the item that is beyond the size of int arr[] which could contain anything. If this value happens to be bigger or equal to the largest value in your data, no change in output is noticeable. If it is smaller than the largest value in your data, it will get sorted in and your largest value will drop out. As the largest value in your data is close to 0 (compared to the full range of a signed 32bit int), this will give you close to 50% chance of the random value affecting the outcome.

While there are some issues in the code posted, the problem is not there, it is in the calling code where you invoke mergeSort with the arguments mergeSort(arr, 0, n) where n is the number of elements in the array.
The problem is your implementation of mergeSort assumes end to be the index to the last element of the array, not the index of the first element after the slice to be sorted.  This calling convention is classic in textbooks, but very error prone and not idiomatic in C or C++ or any of the languages where array indices are zero based.
Note also these issues:

you posted the code twice in the question.
merge recomputes mid as mid = (st + end) / 2; ignoring the value passed as an argument. This has no side effects as the computation evaluates to the same value, but it is useless.
computing mid as mid = (st + end) / 2; is incorrect for large values of st and end where st + end may cause an arithmetic overflow.  You should instead use:
    int mid = st + (end - st) / 2;


saving the second half is not necessary as its elements are never overwritten before they are used.
the main loop makes a special case of first[i] == second[j] and copies both values.  This is OK in this particular case, but not necessary and would break the stability in more general cases where elements that compare identical must remain in the original order.
index variables should have type size_t.

Here is a modified version that uses the more idiomatic index convention, saves only the left part of the slice and uses a simpler loop:
#include <stdio.h>

void merge(int arr[], size_t st, size_t mid, size_t end)
{
    // save the left half
    size_t i, j, k;
    size_t len1 = mid - st;
    int *first = new int[len1];
    for (i = 0; i < len1; i++)
    {
        first[i] = arr[st + i];
    }

    i = 0;
    j = mid;
    k = st;
    while (i < len1 && j < end)
    {
        if (first[i] <= arr[j])
        {
            arr[k++] = first[i++];
        }
        else
        {
            arr[k++] = arr[j++];
        }
    }

    while (i < len1)
    {
        arr[k++] = first[i++];
    }

    delete[] first;
}

void mergeSort(int arr[], size_t st, size_t end)
{
    if (end - st > 1) {
        size_t mid = st + (end - st) / 2;
        mergeSort(arr, st, mid);
        mergeSort(arr, mid, end);
        merge(arr, st, mid, end);
    }
}

void display(const int *arr, size_t st, size_t end) {
    printf("{");
    while (st < end) {
        printf(" %d", arr[st++]);
        if (st < end)
            printf(",");
    }
    printf("}\n");
}

int main(void) {
    int array[] = { 38, 27, 43, 3, 9, 82, 10 };
    size_t count = sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array);

    mergeSort(array, 0, count);
    display(array, 0, count);
    return 0;
}


@armoosa: you can accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.
